Unable to install Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on an old PC
I have an old PC on which I am already using windows 10. I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on it as I have found that it is better for development purposes. I am installing it via USB flash drive which I created on another laptop and installed Ubuntu successfully on it using that same USB drive, which proves that the installation drive is not corrupt.
I had already created some unallocated space from Windows to install Linux, then booted into Ubuntu to install it. But it shows an unexpected error at the last step of installation. After skimming through the log file and searching the internet, I got a hint that the error is occurring while creating partitions. Things I tried after that:

To manually create partitions for Ubuntu root and home directories. I used this post to do the manual partitioning and followed each step clearly. But, got the same error.
Change the SATA mode from IDE to AHCI from BIOS, as was suggested by ChatGPT. But still got the same error.

I have enclosed the log file of last installation attempt (after changing SATA mode). I hope this is enough for detecting the error in the installation.

"Error: Can't have overlapping partitions." Screenshot of your partitions will be helpful.

This question is similar to: How to use manual partitioning during installation?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ventsyv I used this post to do the manual partitioning process during the installation. I followed each step clearly but still got the same error.

As, a quick question/doubt, does the unallocated space necessarily need to be just next to C: drive, where windows is installed? Because the unallocated space I created is not next to C: drive due to lack of space in it.

Depends on how Windows was  installed. You can have C and D drives and then the ut-allocated space. So it doesn't need to next to the C: but usually it won't be in the middle. Also, check what size you are allocating to it.

Are you selecting the free space when trying to create the partition?? Check step #5 here: https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-dual-boot-mode-windows/

Old PC may be either legacy or UEFI. Windows 7 in legacy may have been upgraded to 8,10,..., but the disk partitioning would still be msdos, not gpt.  msdos allows only four primary partitions, so one should be an extended partition so logical partitions may be added (Ubuntu does not care if its partitions are logicals).

So, I was successfully able to install Ubuntu. The issue was that I was using a 3rd party tool to shrink drive in windows (due to the disk management just getting stuck at loading cursor after I tried to shrink a drive). In the third party tool, it showed unallocated space but in disk management it was showing free space. The crucial detail to be noted is

Shrinking logical drive creates free space.

And

Shrinking a Primary drive creates unallocated space.

And the drive I shrunk was logical not primary. After I converted free space to unallocated space, I was able to install Ubuntu 24.04 successfully in that space, from my USB drive.

It seems you do not need to create another partition if you want to boot, cause your old PC is for sure Legacy bios, the supplementary partition is for EFI.
Ubuntu actually not totally finish cooking imposing so this UEFI start. The idea under is respectfull, but when you are in BIOS nothing is clear, you just have to impose that you don't want the new installation some steps, limit a fight !
What you can do is start your machine on live USB, delete the FAT32 partition you do not need, then install "BootRepair" and run it. Then it will be possible to start
